# incorrect format from double to string Book Example C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, double, tostring

So I am following an example from my book that gives me code to type into visual studio. I typed the code exactly as it appears in the textbook but I can't get the program to run.

`Console.Write("{ 0, 8}", tipRate.ToString("F"));` throws

> Input string was not in a correct format

I don't know what the issue is. Maybe something has changed in Visual Studio since the publishing of the book (2012)? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated because I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double dinnerPrice = 10.00;
        double tipRate;
        double tip;

        const double LOWRATE = 0.10;
        const double MAXRATE = 0.25;
        const double TIPSTEP = 0.05;
        const double MAXDINNER = 100.00;
        const double DINNERSTEP = 10.00;

        Console.Write("     Price");

        for (tipRate = LOWRATE; tipRate <= MAXRATE; tipRate += TIPSTEP)
            Console.Write("{ 0, 8}", tipRate.ToString("F"));

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine
        ("——————————————————————————————————————");

       tipRate = LOWRATE;

        while (dinnerPrice <= MAXDINNER)
        {
            Console.Write("{ 0, 8}", dinnerPrice.ToString("C"));

            while (tipRate <= MAXRATE)
            {
                tip = dinnerPrice * tipRate;
                Console.Write("{ 0, 8}",tip.ToString("F"));
                tipRate += 0.05;
            }

            dinnerPrice += DINNERSTEP;
            tipRate = LOWRATE;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo on your string. Remove the whitespace after `{`

```
Console.Write("{0, 8}", tipRate.ToString("F"));
```

Notice that you have the same problem on multiple places, you'll need to fix it everywhere.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that. I just checked the book but it doesn't have that extra space there so I don't know where I got that from. At least it was an easy fix. Thanks for the help!  :)